# zero-offset reflection time from the horizontal seafloor surface at the same depth

Tags: sea-floor

**Question:** What is the zero-offset reflection time from the horizontal seafloor surface at the same depth?

**If I have a point for e.g. at depth = 250m I do know how to solve it, but not sure how to solve this for an horizontal seafloor.**

[image]

Comment: Looks like a homework question?  You'd need to offer your own thoughts/work as a minimum, and no guarantee you'll get much response as such a specific question may not have much widespread interest/use.  Using StackExchange for homework is generally only helpful if you're struggling with a concept or how to do a whole type of question.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the question. The answer given in the question gives an appropriate answer? The zero-offset reflection time for a horizontal reflector 250 m below the point of interest is (250+250)/velocity = 500/3000=0.166... as found by AnaRhisT. The assumption of the horizontal seafloor is what is already assumed in the theory.